# Guidance with my website design.. I use AJAX to update a database "behind the scenes"

Tags: css, ajax, jquery

I have a website where I want the following page to function - it currently works fine on a full page refresh (since each div is populated from a database) - but I'm starting to build in AJAX to update the database behind the page without the browser leaving the page. The following image shows what I want to achieve. Refreshing the whole page can be a bit slow due to the header information and item information might have a lot of images etc.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo9p3.jpg]

I can get it working OK by having my form submit button write out the results in each div area, however when a user returns to the page I want it to show the latest version of the page. Is there a way to change what my submit button on the form does (i.e. when pressed - refresh the "guess" and "guess_info" div areas of the webpage?

My AJAX/Jquery for the form is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            guess: {
                min: 0,
                number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            guess: "Please enter a valid guess.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

process.php just takes the form inputs (e.g. item_id, user_id, guess), and updates the database for new information.

I'm also having difficulties with the CSS side of things, my header and footer are generated by wordpress, however all the dividers detailed below are my own, (which i put inside the "content" divider.

I have managed to split the "content" into 3 columns, but I'm struggling to split my middle column into the divisions shown..

So my "content" divider is 900px, so I have the "middle" as 500px and each column as 200px.

So now I'm looking to divide up my 500px column into 3 rows (which can be as long as needed), first row one column 500px, second row 2 columns, say 150px (the thumbnail is 100px wide) and 350px, the final row would be split, say  100px, 100px, 300px. Can anyone advise me on this? I've tried following a lot of CSS tutorials, but I seem to struggle getting them to sit on top of each other!! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the submit button there are some ways of disabling the default of it.

The first one is

```
<form action="whatever" method="whatever" onsubmit="return myJSFunction();return false;">
```

Or, for keeping your code cleaner you can do:

```
<form action="whatever" method="whatever" onsubmit="return myJSFunction();">
```

For the last one you will need to add in your myJSFunction the following code at the start of it:

```
if(!event) var event = window.event //to prevent browser problems
event.preventDefault();
```

Remember that if everything works in your js function you need to return false. If you return true it might trigger the default call of your submit button.
Once you did this you should call your AJAX request and write/override your html in js.

Regarding the css I don't see why it doesn't work so I will give you a default solution (the following divs should be placed in your "middle" container):

```
<div id="item_info" style="width:500px; height:50px;background-color:green"></div>
<div id="description" style="float:right;width:350px;height:100px;background-color:blue"></div>
<div id="thumbnail" style="width:150px;height:100px;background-color:red"></div>
<div id="guess_info" style="float:right;width:300px;height:100px;background-color:black"></div>
<div id="item2" style="float:left;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:yellow"></div>
<div id="guess" style="float:left;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:pink"></div>
```

I tested this in my editor and it seems to work. Don't bother the colors I used them to get some visibility.
Sorry for the CSS being inlined but just copy the style attribute and put in in your .css page.

If you want each of your rows (the ones that are splitted) to have the same height as their neighbourgs you'll need to change the css a little bit and use some different tricks (but you will have to chose which one could have the biggest height).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks :) I could do with having the spilt rows be the same height if possible - the thumbnail will be a set height, so the biggest would be the description, as for the bottom row - there is less dynamic content in those divs (always a set number of lines) so I don't expect those to be an issue. I'm not sure I understand the submit button side of your answer, I still want the submit button to submit the form to the process.php, but rather than it write out any "echos" in the php in a div, I want it to refresh part of the page, I don't follow the above :(

Comment: Yeah so I think you want the div refreshed only and not the page. You will have to prevent the form to submit the content by default because it will reload the whole page. You should create a PHP page process.php and send your POST/GET values through JavaScript variables (if there is anything to be sent) in an AJAX request. In your response you override your DIV html content with the one echoed (to the response javascript variable) in the process.php page.

Comment: Submitting the form doesn't reload the whole page, at the moment when I click submit it just writes the output of process.php in the <div id="results"></div>.  My process.php is a seperate page on the server which takes the form variables - the article I folowed is this http://www.askaboutphp.com/213/php-and-jquery-submit-a-form-without-refreshing-the-page.html

Comment: But when I refresh the page - that line disappears - so I want that line to be a standard line that is always there, but just gets refreshed following submission - if that's at all possible??

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments!! keep pressing enter to do a line break!!   If you look at the link I sent - you can see my issue - when you refresh the page the results of the process.php vanish - ideally I want the results of that process to be on the page - I've modified the php to add the variables to a database rather than just print them..

Comment: As far as I know there are 2 ways of keeping data in variables when page gets refreshed: If your response is only valuable during the session of a user you can store the answer in the $_SESSION variable (you would then echo the $_SESSION["varname"] in your div). If you want to have access in later sessions (e.g. user gets out of the site and comes back few hours later) you should store your data in a SQL table. Is the CSS part working?

Comment: I can't test the CSS until I get home to where I have my code. I do have the variables saved in a SQL table - so in the picture my variables are $guess etc, and the form box will take a new guess as an input, pressing the button sends an updated guess to process.php which updates the database, but my "guess" is not updated (on the page) unless I reload the whole page. So what I'm after is when pressing the submit - it does what it does now but also reloads what is inside the <guess> div then that would be perfect.

Comment: If I can get it working it has use all across the website - for example the "add to history" button - sends the item_id and the user_id to a SQL table holding "histories", and the right column shows the user the history - so on the click of that one, it would do the same mechanics as the guess button, update the history table and reload both the "add to history" and the "history" div (since I need the "add to history" to change to "remove from history" ...  a bit like a "favourites" panel I guess

Comment: So: Your guess is updated to the database and this works when the page reloads but when you send your form with your guess in the input it doesn't write it in the guessed div. How about adding an id to your input: <input type="text" id="inputguess"/> and in your javascript function you use the following JS code: var inputValue = $('#inputguess').val(); then in your guess div you write: $('#inputguess').html("<p>"+inputValue+"</p>"); (put this line in your submitHandler)

Comment: Currently my code is along the lines of: <div id = "guess"> $guessed = MYSQLquery to check for guesses... if($guessed == 0) { do nothing } else { echo "your guess is:" .$guess.;}  following this is a input box where you can put in a value for your guess and a button which sends the form to process.php and updates the database which holds the $guess...   so when I refresh the page it will be using the latest $guess..   but because when I submit the form at the moment the page isn't refreshed, the $guess is still the "old guess" because none of the page is refreshed..  does this make any sense?

Comment: Yes it does sense. Why don't you overrite the text echoed in $guess variable with jQuery's .html() function? This will change the content of your "guess" div without having to reload the page.

Comment: Would that work? I've had a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_html.asp

Comment: Would that work? I've had a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_html.asp as usual struggling to follow what is needed.. so when I see the page the first time it will be the page as loaded (which works) then the .html() would replace the part in my <div> for the result of the process.php - how would I have that happen on click on the form submit button? and the example on my link only shows   $("p").html("W3Schools"); so my W3Schools would need to be the result of the process.php .. could I have different buttons replacing different parts (and also doing the update of the MYSQL)

Comment: OH - so actually above if I just changed $('#results').html(data); to '#guess' it would replace what's in my guess id :) if that works then that's genius! then it's figuring out how to work the other button also

Comment: Yes exactly this is what you have to do to update your div text in real time. If you're using <button> tags just add a onclick="javaScriptFunction()" and in your javaScriptFunction() have implement the $('#idName').html("text"); You can put this code when you submit a form by adding it just before your $.post request for example.

Comment: Hi - I've tested the CSS and it appears to work, however when I try to combine it with my existing side panels it doesn't work - GRRR. How would I add a left panel (200px) and a right panel (200px) to the code?

Comment: the following code seems to work perfectly: <div id="right" style="float:right;width:200px;height:200px;background-color:red"></div>
<div id="left" style="float:left;width:200px;height:200px;background-color:blue"></div>
<div id="middle" style="float:left;width:500px;height:200px;background-color:green"> INSERT THE DIVS FROM MY FIRST POST HERE </div> (worked for me:)

Comment: I think it's official that I don't understand css!! thanks for all your help today!! Can I ask - where are you based? Also do I need to contain the above in a large 900px container?

Comment: I've not enough reputation to chat yet, I think what I was missing was the height...  is it easy to make the height of the right andd left panels as dynamic?

Comment: You're welcome. Based in Europe, GMT+1. Yes you should wrap all this in a 900px or your right divs will stick on the far-right of your screen and your left on the far-left! If you want it centered just add a margin:auto on the top-level div. Yes you can make the height of the left and right panels dynamic (e.g. you don't need to specify the height in the css). You can specifiy a min-height if you wish to display it.

Comment: Cheers, you've been very useful, just trying to re-build my webpage into these new divisions.... fingers crossed

Comment: No problem really. Once you re done with your problem mark this answer (the first one). It will prevent people from answering a problem that has been solved ;)